# iOS: SQLite Russian letters turn into strange symbols

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite, encoding

I am inserting Russian words into SQLite DB and inside the database (using some DBMS software) they are looking good. But when I retrieve them, the look like this: —É–ª. –°–∞–º–æ–≥–æ –∫—Ä—É—Ç–æ–≥–æ —á—É–≤–∞–∫–∞.

Insert code:

```
NSString *sql = @"INSERT INTO (. . .) "
    " VALUES (. . . )";
    sqlite3_stmt *insert;
    int result = sqlite3_prepare_v2(self.db, [sql UTF8String], -1, &insert, NULL);
    if (result == SQLITE_OK) {
        sqlite3_bind_text(insert, 1, [favouriteAction.nameAction UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
```

. . .

Select code:

```
NSString *sql = nil;
    sql = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM UserFavourites"];
    sqlite3_stmt *select;

    int result = sqlite3_prepare_v2(self.db, [sql UTF8String], -1, &select, NULL);

    NSMutableArray* userFavourites = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:20];
    NSLog(@"SQLITE_OK %d", result);
    if (result == SQLITE_OK) {

//        sqlite3_bind_int(select, 1, (int)user_id);

        while (sqlite3_step(select) == SQLITE_ROW) {
            NSMutableArray *values = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:8];
            ActionCreation* ac = [[ActionCreation alloc]init];
            // get the nameAction:
            [values addObject:
             [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s", sqlite3_column_text(select, 0)]];
```

How to fix this problem?
Thank you.

Comment: SQLite does not change the bytes in a string. Check the code that generates or displays the strings.

Comment: Even NSLog gives same result.